# ¿Cómo puedo sobrescribir un archivo fstream?

Tags: dev-c++

estoy estoy queriendo ingresar datos nuevos y que se eliminen los datos viejos de un archivo creado con ofstream, pero simplemente se van agregando más datos en vez de eliminar los viejos

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < limit-1; i++){
        ofstream archivo;
        archivo.open(ar_name, ios::out|ios::app);
        if(archivo.is_open()){
            archivo<<"asd hgf asd";
        }
        archivo.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cambia el flag `ios::app` por `ios::trunc` y comenta el resultado.

Comment: sí, gracias. Funciona bien